# Command line tool to create a pdf file with a4 sized pages from a poster pdf

Tags: command-line, pdf

I am looking for a command line tool that "converts" a pdf file (whose size is larger than a4) into a *single* pdf file that consists of multiple a4 pages. The new pdf file, when printed, should look like the original content without scaling the original.

Searching the internet, I found `pdfposter`. Yet, it seems to require the size of the input pdf file which I don't know.

So, is there a tool that does that.

Comment: What would each of these A4 pages contain? How can it be the same as the original when printed? Do you mean printing and then arranging pieces like a puzzle?

Comment: Yes: the entirety of the printed pages should contain the same as the original.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain. You say that when printed it should look the same but I think you mean that it shouldn't look the same but it should look like a puzzle of the original. Also, why don't you just find out the size of the original? There are tools that can do this (I don't remember the names now; maybe a new question?)

Comment: @terdon, I am not sure if I understand your comment. When I print the individual pages and then lay them out in "correct" order, it should look like the original, not like a puzzle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a tool that can do what you want. I explained it over at askubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/a/1155892/394569

It's called plakativ and its main interfaces is a GUI. But it also has a command line interface that allows you to do what you want including specifying borders to glue the pages together.

If you find a bug, please post it at https://gitlab.mister-muffin.de/josch/plakativ